# Json via POST dando erro

Tags: java, json

Olá! Estou enviando um Json através de um HttpClient e ele está retornando um erro sobre header. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
JsonDeDados = sender.sendMessageDATA();
            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(infos, JsonDeDados));
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonDeDados);

            post.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando a declaração do Header

```
JsonDeDados = sender.sendMessageDATA();
            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(infos, JsonDeDados));
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonDeDados);

            post.setEntity(entity);
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Testa e diz pra gente se funcionou

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado. Será que era só isso que estava faltando?

Comment: Se você incrementou apenas essa linha e o código retornou resposta positiva, possivelmente sim